# How to display in the Title the numer of marks on a scatter-plot

Tags: tableau-api

How can I capture the number of Marks in a scatter-plot?   I want to display it in the worksheet Title.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be able to use the `SIZE()` function to count the number of marks. https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_tablecalculation.htm

**Edit:**
If you apply your `SIZE()` table calculation along the specific dimensions that define your marks you should get the total number of marks accessible at each point.

[image]

Comment: Thank you...I thought of size(), but the only values I can muster is 1 or None... Still tinkering to figure it out.  I am looking for numbers in the millions.  I may not understand how to implement Size() adequately enough.  Even sum(Number of Records) just returns 1

Comment: Have you tried playing with how the size function is being computed as a table calculation? I found I needed to switch to specific dimensions in order to be able to access the number of marks at each point.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the `WINDOW_COUNT` function.

```
WINDOW_COUNT(COUNTD([Number of Records]))
or
WINDOW_COUNT(SUM([Number of Records]))
```

I get the same result in either case and both return the number of marks in my view as indicated in the lower left of the sheet tab.

[image]

Then update your `Compute Using` to the level of detail of your marks.
[image]

Comment: Hi... disregard the part where marks is 61, yet displayed marks is 8.   I think that's be cause 53 are all sitting on 0,0.  I'll verify, but that's why, I'm sure.

Comment: but not worry, I will stay with it, and let you know what I was doing wrong.  I am very grateful for the screen shots, to confirm I'm pretty close

Comment: One last observation, then I'm giving up.  When I duplicate the worksheet, clear it, and drag [Number of Records] to Marks card, or Detail.... the count is correct.  The only thing I see different is that on the duplicate WS, when I drag NoR, it drags as a 'Sum(Number of Records)'.  On the original WS it drags as just [Number of Records].   If on the original WS, I 'edit in shelf', I see sum(Nor), but not when I drag it.  On the dup WS, when I insert it into the Title, it actually says Sum(NoR)..... on the orig WS, it just says NoR... which is always "1"  Screw it!  Thank you for your help.

Comment: have you tried any of your other metrics rather than NoR?

Comment: yeah.. I've tried every dimension to just get a number.  Sometimes that helps to see the problem.  In this same workbook, I have worksheets where I get the size() to work.  It's just this scatter-plot that's giving me fits.   It's ok... It was just a number to let users know what kind of volume was being represented.   It's cool... I am very grateful for your help.   If I ultimately find out where I'm getting it wrong, I will definitely return here and post it.

Comment: Strange. I even mocked it up on a scatterplot to make sure it worked. Hopefully you figure it out.

Comment: I probably have something conflicting... I will not forget your effort to help.  I think I have tapped onto something because when I drag NoR, it 's not SUM(NorR).....  I will figure it out... :)   You have helped me alot.... please know that.

Comment: why if I have sum(Number of Records), Tableau shows a range?  Like  1 to 343555